# SSRS Error: 'Value' is not a member of 'ReportExprHostImpl...Action0_ActionExprHost'

Tags: sql, vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to set up a rule in SSRS to where if a user clicks on a PDF filename  'Document.pdf', the user is taken to a URL ex. 'www.website.com/Document.pdf'.

To do so, I'm using an expression under Placeholder Properties > Action > Go To URL:

=IIf(Fields!ID.Value = "Document.pdf", "www.website.com/Document.pdf", "false")

[image]

Upon running the report, I receive the error:

```
The ActionInfo.Action.Hyperlink expression for the text box ‘ID’ contains an error: [BC30456] 'Value' is not a member of 'ReportExprHostImpl.ID_TextBoxExprHost.ActionInfo_ActionInfoExprHost.Action0_ActionExprHost'.
```

I receive the same error in using Me.Value, rather than Fields!ID.Value.

I haven't encountered this problem in the past, so I'm curious as to whether this is specific to report builder actions.

Comment: Are you sure that there's not another action on the **text box** (not placeholder as shown) that is using `Me.value`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
=IIf(Fields!ID.Value = "Document.pdf", "http://www.website.com/Document.pdf", nothing)
```

Note the VS warning message:

> The value ‘www.website.com/Document.pdf’ of the Hyperlink property of
>   the text box ‘Textbox18’ has an invalid schema.  URLs in reports may
>   only use http://, https://, ftp://, mailto:

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, doesn't seem to fix it though as I receive the same error

Comment: @BenWS, Did you check the ID field values? It seems the ID field Value property is not recognized.

Comment: I don't understand why this wouldn't be recognized, as this field is referenced as a display value in the report - so if 'Fields!ID.Value' is recognized in another area of report builder i would imagined it should be recognized here - unless the Value property can't be used under Actions

Comment: @BenWS, I see you are using the action property in a Place Holder try replicate the same expression in the whole cell instead.